# Joomla 3 Article Gallery View stopped displaying articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, jquery

I have a website with some menu items using the Article / Gallery View option to display a list of articles in blog style. It has been working perfectly for a few years now, but it stopped working in the last days / weeks. It does not display any articles. I have not touched anything on this part of the website. If I switch the menu item to e.g. Articles / Category articles, it works fine. So I suspect that the Gallery View component got broken somehow. Does anybody else have the same problem? Any hints on the possible reason, solution?
You can check the broken page [here](https://gonativeguide.com/de/touren/budapest):

Thanks, 
W.

Comment: The page you linked works fine; anyway, if you want some help you should start by looking into the server and client error logs (apache/nginx and the browser console) and report them here; otherwise how can we help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the gallery component mentioned in my question above belongs to an external template, so I contacted the template developer. It turned out that error (only visible in browsers running on windows) was caused by an outdated script file.

Comment: May we know which script file was outdated?